# chrome navigator в json

Tags: javascript, json

Задача получить-передать navigator на сервер, и преобразовать в обычный формат.

Для получение и передачи использовал

```html
var _navigator = {};
for (var i in navigator) _navigator[i] = navigator[i];
console.log(JSON.stringify(_navigator));
```

Но он не формирует внутренние массивы например plugins/mimeTypes.

Есть решения/идеи как сделать в json? или получить оригинальный массив из navigator.plugins в string

Comment: `plugins` и `mimeTypes` не формирует, потому что есть циклические ссылки, их в тексте передать напрямую нельзя. Если это необходимо сделать - нужно на стороне клиента и сервера условиться о замене циклической ссылки каким-либо значением и при парсинге их подменять обратно на ссылки.